# C# to get database and collection in cosmos db sql api

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am writing C# application where trying to retrieve database and collection using following connection strings. But not sure what I am missing.

```
const string cosmos = @"<connection-string>";
const string cosmos_database = "Enctr";
const string cosmos_collection = "account";

SqlConnection client = new SqlConnection(cosmos);
var database = client.GetDatabase(cosmos_database);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cosmos_collection);
```

Its not allowing me to use below 2 lines:

```
var database = client.GetDatabase(cosmos_database);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cosmos_collection);
```

Comment: SqlConnection is not a cosmos db client, totally different thing

Comment: Have a try this: ```CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmos);
var database = client.GetDatabase(cosmos_database);
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cosmos_collection);```

Comment: Thanks Steve. It complains about CosmosClient. I tried to include using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos; but it doesn't allow

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package for CosmosClient. However, the line var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cosmos_collection) is not allowed. It says - "Database doesn't contain definition for GetCollection....."

Comment: What's your version of SDK?

Comment: If your SDK version is latest, please try this:```CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmos); 
            var database = client.GetDatabase(cosmos_database);
            var collection = database.GetContainer(cosmos_collection);```

Comment: Looks good now. My SDK is 3.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Crowcoder says, SqlConnection is not a cosmos db client, you should use CosmosClient and use `GetContainer()` to get your container in Cosmos DB. Try the following code:

```
const string cosmos = @"<connection-string>";
const string cosmos_database = "Enctr";
const string cosmos_collection = "account";

CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmos);
var database = client.GetDatabase(cosmos_database);
var collection = database.GetContainer(cosmos_collection);
```